# Cannot GET /api/tasks

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, body-parser

Every time I call: http://localhost:3000/api/tasks am getting a Cannot GET /api/tasks

My server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var BodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var tasks = require('./routes/tasks');

var port = 3000;

var app = express();

//View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

// Body Parser MW
app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('api', tasks);

app.listen(port, function(){
console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

I am still learning the ropes. Thank you in advance

tasks.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app= express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs')
var db = mongojs('mongodb://<user>.:<****>@ds125365.mlab.com:25365/mytasklist_wafalme', ['tasks'])

// Get All Tasks
app.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(tasks);
 });
});

// Get Single Tasks
app.get('/tasks/:id', function(req, res, next){
db.tasks.findOne({_id: mangojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(err, task){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(task);
 });
});
module.exports = app;
```

I have attached the task.js file that runs in the routes folder with the index.js

Comment: please show us your ./routes/tasks.js file

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `app.use('/api', tasks);`? And as @AnuratChapanond mentions, please add your tasks route file.

Answer (score 3):

Use an absolute route to define the API routing context:

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', tasks);
```

Always include a forward slash (`/`) at the beginning of your routes.